# Can someone help me to do this exercise

Tags: c

I want to get the correct result without using pointers and arrays.

Here's the code (variable j, k removed being useless):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char c;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; c != '#'; i++) {
        c = getchar();
        printf("%c", c);
    }

    i -= 1;
    printf("le nombre de charactere dans cet phrase est :\t %d \n", i);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Delete the question temporarily, spend more time rewriting it with the best of your efforts (that includes showing your coding attempt).

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char c ;
  int i ;
  int j ;
  int k ;
  for(i=0;c!='#';i++){
    c=getchar();
    printf("%c",c);
  }
  i = i-1;
  printf("\n");
  printf("le nombre de charactere dans cet phrase est :\t %d \n",i);
  return 0;
}

Comment: its what i did i swear i m new so i just want to to know how

Comment: @ChristianNeverdal look at the code

Comment: Please edit the question, unformatted code like this is sadly nearly useless

Comment: @FELIXCompany Please edit your question for readability. You want to compute the offset to the longest word and the length of the word for printing the difference and the word.

Comment: okey wait 1 seconde

Comment: Please insert your code as markdown and not as images.

Comment: and now ? pls tell me that u can help me please ?

Comment: @FELIXCompany This time, I've added the required information given by you. Next time, keep your question look clean, otherwise you won't get helped from anyone.

Comment: so ? someone have a solution of this ?

Comment: @FELIXCompany You did not mention getchar() as the input method, so I need to change my code.

Comment: @FELIXCompany In an earlier version, you needed to output the word as well. However, this disappeared and you did not clarify the input method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Used this code to obtain that output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char text[1024];
    int biggest = 0, newBiggest = 0, stopCondition = 0, phrase = 0;

    puts("Enter text, end with #");

    do
    {
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", text);
        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
        {
            if (text[i] == '#')
            {
                stopCondition = 1;
                break;
            }
        
            if (text[i] == ' ' || text[i] == ',' || text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '\n' || text[i] == '?')
            {
                if (newBiggest > biggest)
                    biggest = newBiggest;
                newBiggest = 0;
            }
            else
                newBiggest++;


            if (text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '\n' || text[i] == '?')
            {
                printf("In phrase %d biggest word found have %d chars!\n",++phrase,biggest);
                newBiggest = 0;
                biggest = 0;
            }
        }
    }while(!stopCondition);

    return 0;
}
```

To obtain the global biggest word and in witch pharase it apear i let it as a challange for you, if you struggle doing that let me know and i give you some tips.

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\

Changes you need to do acording new specifications:
[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char c;
    int biggest = 0, newBiggest = 0, stopCondition = 0, phrase = 0;

    puts("Enter text, end with #");

    do
    {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == '#')
        {
            stopCondition = 1;
            break;
        }
    
        if (c == ' ' || c == ',' || c == '.' || c == '!' || c == '\n' || c == '?')
        {
            if (newBiggest > biggest)
                biggest = newBiggest;
            newBiggest = 0;
        }
        else
            newBiggest++;


        if (c == '.' || c == '!' || c == '?')
        {
            printf("In phrase %d biggest word found have %d chars!\n",++phrase,biggest);
            newBiggest = 0;
            biggest = 0;
        }
    }while(!stopCondition);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i know its fair but u shouldn't use the tables or str or pointers

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to find `The length of the longest word in the sentence`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int longest_word_len = 0, temp_len = 0;
    char text[100];
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", text);
    for (int i = 0;  text[i]!= '#'; i++) {
        if(text[i] == ' '){
            if(temp_len > longest_word_len){
                longest_word_len = temp_len;
            }
            temp_len = 0;
        }else{
            temp_len++;
        }
    }
    
    printf("the length of the longest word in the sentence %d", longest_word_len);

    return 0;
}
```

The Process is:

1. take the whole string at once
2. iterate over the string and find the longest word length

I don't know french though. However, I hope that I've gone to the right way. You should be able to find out the other solutions by yourself.

Comment: i know its fair but u shouldn't use the tables or str or pointers

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me from the context, what type of word delimiters you have in the input. It is also unclear, if the input can be of arbitrary length. It is also unclear to me, if you must use getchar().

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) 
{ 
  int i = 0;
  char buffer[100] = "";
  char wmax[100] = "";
  int wlen = 0;
  int l_wmax = 0;
  int c = 'a';
  while (c != '#')
  {
    c = getchar();
    if (c == ' ')
    {
      if (l_wmax < wlen)
      {
        //write NULL
        buffer[i] = '\0';
        //copy buffer to wmax, careful with NULL
        strncpy(wmax, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);
        l_wmax = wlen;
      }
      i = 0;
      wlen = 0;
    } 
    else
    {
      buffer[i] = c;
      wlen += 1;
    }
    i += 1;
  }
  printf("longest word: %s, length: %d", wmax, l_wmax);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: i know its fair but u shouldn't use the tables or str or pointers

Comment: `getchar()` retuns an `int`.  Best to use `int c;` to distinguish the typical 257 different results.